# a hole keeps forming in my object and i don't know hwo to remove it

Tags: loop

I'm very new to blender and I'm learning how to model a chair with blender guru's tutorial. All seem fine til I realized there's a tiny hole when I apply the subdivider surface and I have no idea how to remove it. I've tried creating loop cuts, removing the edge and some other stuff. Can someone help me? I'll be attaching pictures. Thanks[image]

The rest of the screenshots are here https://i.stack.imgur.com/o47jY.jpg

Comment: hello, maybe it's a face inside your mesh? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/bb654b953c1b413b8a2efadcfdc16de3 here it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inner faces, the *Subdivision Surface* modifier try to smooth them and it gives this hole, so delete these faces:

[image]

Also, activate the *Mirror "Clipping"* option so that when you extrude faces along the axis the vertices stick to the axis and it doesn't create these inner faces:

[image]

Comment: worked flawlessly. thank you very much!!